# How can I refactor my main.js file to be more modular in its structure for a large application?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a large Vue application to replace the front end of an existing legacy php project.  Due to its nature this will not be an SPA but will require access to a large number of Vue components that will be rendered on the fly when called upon from a PHP file like this:

```
<div id='app'>
        <{{ $name }} v-bind='{{ htmlspecialchars(json_encode( $vbinds )) }}'>
    </{{ $name }}>
</div>
```

For this reason the `main.js` will end up having 50+ components.  I have only included a few below to save space.  This is what my current main.js file looks like

**current main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import ConfirmHolidays from "./components/Holidays/BookHolidayDates/ConfirmHolidays.vue";
import RequestHolidays from "./components/Holidays/BookHolidayDates/RequestHolidays.vue";
import HolidaySummary from "./components/Holidays/HolidaySummary/HolidaySummary.vue";

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
vuetify,
  components: {
    ConfirmHolidays,
    RequestHolidays,
    HolidaySummary,
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

However, when I will start to have 50+ parent components it will become unmanageable, so I would like to somehow restructure the architecture so instead I would have folders/modules set up grouping sets of components together, something like this:

**holidays.js**

```
import ConfirmHolidays from "./BookHolidayDates/ConfirmHolidays.vue";
import RequestHolidays from "./BookHolidayDates/RequestHolidays.vue";
import HolidaySummary from "./HolidaySummary/HolidaySummary.vue";

export default {
        components: {
                ConfirmHolidays,
                RequestHolidays,
                HolidaySummary
        }
}
```

**proposed main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

import holidays from "../modules/Holidays"

new Vue({
  modules: {
    holidays
  },
  vuetify,
  el: '#app',
}).$mount('#app')
```

At the moment, this builds ok but it my app fails to locate the `holliday-summary` component:
`Unknown custom element: <holiday-summary> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option` which previously worked fine.

I have seen this method of using `modules: { ... }` here: https://github.com/laander/vue-modular  but I'm not sure if that is just part of this package or if it is something included in Vue.

How can I better structure my app, having in mind that I will need access to 50+ components from a root level?

Comment: Are you using webpack? If yes you could simply have all components automatically imported, there are some instructions on the vue website: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components .But why would you import 100+ components in the main file? You would create a massive app...

Comment: I'm reskinning a large legacy php project with a new frontend  - so it is not an SPA. This means there will probably be 50 different sections which a php script needs access to in order to call upon them individually and render.  Each base section may have 1 or 2 sub-components which can be registered within the parent.

Comment: Have you considered registering them globally? For example https://sebastiandedeyne.com/exposing-multiple-vue-components-as-a-plugin/

Comment: That sounds a good idea! Would the plugin get chunked? My other aim is to not end up with a very large sized build fille (app.js)